# Button 'in cart' not working anymore

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I found out that clicking on "in cart" button on a product page is not working anymore. (www.deli-discountnl) while on the overview page when you click on the basket it still works. And I am having a `system.log` of 500 mb!?

This is the first line:

> 2016-10-10T10:16:37+02:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   Entity: line 96: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in
>   lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 383 2016-10-10T10:16:37+02:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():
>   ><sortorder/><location_picker>0</location_picker></dhlforyou_1456932693927_927><
>   in
>   lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 383 2016-10-10T10:16:37+02:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():
>   ^  in
>   lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 383

This is line 383 of the `config.php`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, $this->_elementClass);
```

What is going wrong here? Even more important, how can I fix it?

It is a multistore and with the other site (different template) www.vizenco.nl and www.bakmina.nl there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

search in your magento *.xml files for string `><sortorder/><location_picker>0</location_picker></dhlforyou_1456932693927_927><` (in `app/code` directory), seems it's just syntax error in xml file

pS: Better way to search for `</dhlforyou_1456932693927_927>`, because xml can xml may be with `\n` symbols (new line)

Comment: Where can I find that? I found some in add/design/frontend/ default/ MAG090173/layout.

Comment: I am no using DHL, so how can it be called ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know your installation. May be any third-party module added that?

Comment: I disabled the DHL module, works now.But now it is only working on the productpage but not on the homepage, with the new products in Firefox but not in Google Chroom.